# rJava generics type

Tags: java, r, rjava

I have been playing with rJava package, but since it seems that rJava is not aware of Java generic types, I have difficulties creating java object with generic type parameters. If I have a java class like:

```
public class A<T> {
    private B<T> b;
    public A(B<T> b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

I would like to create an A object from R session using `.jnew()` by passing a B object already created (with instantiated type parameter), but rJava always gives error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: What's the exact syntax that you are using when you call `.jnew()`? Are you passing it arguments?  Please specify them exactly.

Comment: Here's a worked example. You'll need to download the Tetrad jar from [here](http://www.phil.cmu.edu/projects/tetrad_download/download/tetrad-5.2.1-3.jar) (19mb) and the sample dataset, charity.txt, from [here](http://www.phil.cmu.edu/projects/tetrad_download/download/workshop/Data/charity.txt). Set up in R: `setwd("wherever/you/put/the/data/")`, 
`library(rJava)`, 
`.jinit("path/to/tetrad-5.2.1-3.jar")`. All of the following works: 1. `filename = .jnew("java/lang/String", "charity.txt")`, 2. `datafile = .jnew("java/io/File", filename)`, 3. `reader = .jnew("edu/cmu/tetrad/data/DataReader")`,

Comment: 4. `delim = J("edu/cmu/tetrad/data/DelimiterType")`, 5. `reader$setDelimiter(delim$TAB)`, 6. `dataset = reader$parseTabular(datafile)` . But the following doesn't work: 7. `gesinstance = .jnew("edu/cmu/tetrad/search/Ges", dataset)` . reader$parseTabular returns a DataSet, and the Ges class is supposed to be created with a DataSet argument. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I think the reason is because Ges implements two interfaces, GraphSearch and GraphScorer, and the GraphScorer is just a double. In the Java source: `public interface GraphScorer {
    double scoreDag(Graph dag);
}`

Comment: I have no experience with Java so unfortunately I can't construct an example that's simpler on the Java side, sorry! The Tetrad source distribution is available for a slightly [earlier version](http://www.phil.cmu.edu/projects/tetrad_download/download/tetraddist-5.1.0-8.zip), if that's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of moving parts in this question.  Digging through the documentation for the various parts, I think that you need to do this on the line that broke:

```
gesinstance = .jnew("edu/cmu/tetrad/search/Ges", .jcast(dataset, "edu/cmu/tetrad/data/DataSet"))
```

The key difference being the call to `.jcast` on the second argument. (I don't have R installed, so I could not test this - If it doesn't work, I will update my answer based on any feedback you can provide on new error messages.)

So then the question is "why that?"  The answer seems to be:

1. On the Java side, `DataReader.parseTabularData` returns an object with type `DataSet` as you noted, but `DataSet` is an interface not a class.  That necessarily means that the actual object returned is of some class that implements the `DataSet` interface.
2. For reasons that aren't immediately clear to me, the rJava package does not really handle polymorphism well.  It requires that you call methods with an "exact" signature match to the objects that you are passing.  In this case, you will need to "up-cast" from whatever specific class you got to the interface `DataSet`.  See the documentation for `.jnew` (https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/rJava/html/jnew.html), especially for the arguments that they denote by "...".  This refers you to the corresponding part of the documentation for `.jcall` (https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/rJava/html/jcall.html), when then explains the requirement to call `.jcast` (https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/rJava/html/jcast.html) with some examples.

The error that you got `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>` was telling you that the JVM could not find the constructor that you called.  This was mysterious looking in the example that you posted in the comments. (It might be good to edit your question, by the way, and include that information up there for posterity.)  The code certainly looks right, and, knowing Java, I intuitively expected the interface to respect the polymorphism of the Java.  Given that (for whatever reason), the interface to R does "exact" type matching without considering inheritance, it's clear that it will not find a constructor due to reason #1 above.

Finally, I didn't actually encounter any Java classes using generics in my limited exploration of Tetrad.  As it turns out, that was a complete red herring though.  Should it be an issue in the future, you'll probably want to check out "Type Erasure"  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  If you were interfacing between Java and C, C++, Fortran, any language that Java considers "native," then you'd deal with the generics in the native code by dealing in the type-erased forms.  The rJava interface may be different though, since this seems to fall into the same general type of structure that tripped you up on your current problem. (Maybe worthy of its own bounty later!)

Comment: Thank you!! This solves the problem I was facing, and gives me a better understanding of rJava (and Java itself). I'm not sure how to edit the question, because I didn't ask the original question, and you've discovered that it's about a totally separate problem to what I was facing. Perhaps I should make it a two-part question?